# Hadoop services are not starting after enabling security PriviledgedActionException (auth:KERBEROS)

Tags: security, hadoop, kerberos, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I have a Cloudera cluster of version 5

here i am facing a problem after enabling Hadoop security Hadoop services are not starting.

I am getting error on YARN:

```
PriviledgedActionException as:mapred/cdh4hdm@IMP.CO.IN (auth:KERBEROS) cause:java.io.IOException: Couldn't setup connection for mapred/cdh4hdm@IMP.CO.IN to cdh4hdm/172.26.43.40:8020
3:23:49.298 PM  INFO    org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService   
Service org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager failed in state INITED; cause: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Error creating done directory: [hdfs://cdh4hdm:8020/user/history/done]
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Error creating done directory: [hdfs://cdh4hdm:8020/user/history/done]
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager.serviceInit(HistoryFileManager.java:503)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory.serviceInit(JobHistory.java:89)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:108)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer.serviceInit(JobHistoryServer.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer.launchJobHistoryServer(JobHistoryServer.java:155)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer.main(JobHistoryServer.java:165)
```

if someone have any idea please comment any suggestion or help would be really appreciated

**Update 1**

hadoop fs -ls command is also not running

```
hadoop fs -ls
14/03/04 15:17:52 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:cloudera (auth:KERBEROS) cause:javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
14/03/04 15:17:52 WARN ipc.Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
14/03/04 15:17:52 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:cloudera (auth:KERBEROS) cause:java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
ls: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]; Host Details : local host is: "cdh4hdm/172.26.43.40"; destination host is: "cdh4hdm":8020;
```

**Update 2**

when i am ruuning sample hadoop MapReduce then also getting error

```
hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-examples.jar pi 10 10000
Number of Maps  = 10
Samples per Map = 10000
14/03/04 16:00:36 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:cloudera (auth:KERBEROS) cause:javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
14/03/04 16:00:36 WARN ipc.Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed tofind any Kerberos tgt)]
14/03/04 16:00:36 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:cloudera (auth:KERBEROS) cause:java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused byGSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberostgt)]; Host Details : local host is: "cdh4hbm/172.26.43.41"; destination host is: "cdh4hdm":8020;
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:764)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1351)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:651
)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1724)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.estimatePi(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.run(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.main(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:363)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$1.run(Client.java:620)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.handleSaslConnectionFailure(Client.java:583)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2600(Client.java:314)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1318)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$1700(Client.java:314)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:659)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:655)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:654)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:121)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:187)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:223)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:193)
    ... 45 more
```

Comment: I found no solution and at last reverted the authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to bad configuration. Nowadays Hadoop security is much mature with kerberos authorization, cloudera provide nice and precise document on enabling kerberos on cloudera VM [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-quickly-configure-kerberos-for-your-apache-hadoop-cluster/). One can use it and take advantage of this post.